# Populating form with data using ajax response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently having a problem passing the values into the edit form using an ajax response, if I just respond by html and render the form it gets the email value passed in. But I'm having no luck trying to do this via ajax. Is there anything I'm doing glaringly wrong?

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#edit-admin-modal').modal('show');
$('#admin_email').val('<%= @admin.email %>');
console.log('<%= @admin.email %>');
```

**index.html.haml**

```
  - @admins.each do |admin|
        %tr#admin[admin]
          %td= admin.email
          %td= admin.last_sign_in_at
          %td= admin.last_sign_in_ip
          %td.buttonColumn
            %button.adminShow.adminButton.btn.btn-primary{ type: 'button', disabled: 'disabled' } Show
          %td.buttonColumn
            = link_to 'Edit', "admins/#{admin.id}/edit", remote: true, class: 'btn btn-warning adminButton admin-edit'
          %td.buttonColumn
            = link_to 'Delete', "admins/#{admin.id}", method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger adminButton'
```

**_edit_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for @admin, :url => {:action => "update", :id => @admin.id} do |f|
  .form-inputs.modal-body
    .form-group.row
      = f.label :email, 'Email',  class:('col-sm-2 col-form-label'), required: true
      .col-sm-10
        = f.email_field :email, class:('form-control')
        %div#emailUnique.confirmMessage
    .form-group.row
      = f.label :password, 'Password', class:('col-sm-2 col-form-label'), required: true
      .col-sm-10
        = f.password_field :password, class:('form-control')
    .form-group.row
      = f.label :confirm_Password, 'Confirm Password', class:('col-sm-2 col-form-label')
      .col-sm-10
        = f.password_field :password_confirmation, class:('form-control'), required: true
        %div#confirmMessage.confirmMessage
  .modal-footer
    = f.submit 'Update Admin', class:('btn btn-primary'), id:('admin-submit')
```

**_edit_account_modal.html.haml**

```
.modal#edit-admin-modal.fade{:role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-dialog{:role => "document"}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
          %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} ×
        %h4.modal-title Update Account
        = render 'edit_form'
```

**admins_controller.rb**

```
def edit
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{redirect_to admins_url}
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: What's the console output?, none problem?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma the console output is what I expect and shows the email I forgot to add that in

Comment: Its better to use the route helpers or polymorpic routing rather than string interpolation. Bad: `link_to 'Delete', "admins/#{admin.id}""`. Good: `link_to 'Delete', @admin`.

Comment: And just specify your form as  `<%= form_for @admin %>` - it makes it easier to re-use and leverages convention over configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not bother editing each field individually. Instead maybe resend your form using ERB in your JS response.

```
$('#edit-admin-modal').modal('show');
$('.modal-content .some-form-wrapper').html('<%= j render "edit_form" %>')
```

This will *behave like* the HTML response in rails.

Make sure to rename the file to `.js.erb`.

Comment: I've found a small problem with this because new and edit now use the same modal if I click edit and then close it, then go back on to new it will still be prefilled in. Any way to fix this?

Comment: If you use AJAX to load your edit form, you should do the same for new. Assuming that you're sending a new record to the new form, it should have blank fields.

Comment: Glad I could help :)